# Excel Formula works in conditional formatting but doesn't in code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with a formula in VBA. It works in conditional formatting and in excel itself, but I can't use it from VBA level

This is the code:

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=IF(ISERR(FIND(" & Chr(34) & "-" & Chr(34) & ";" & s_adr_1 & ";2))=FALSE;TRUE;IF(ISERR(FIND(" & Chr(34) & "…" & Chr(34) & ";" & s_adr_1 & ";2))=FALSE;TRUE;IF(ISERR(FIND(" & Chr(34) & ".." & Chr(34) & ";" & s_adr_1 & "))=FALSE;TRUE;IF(ISBLANK(" & s_adr_1 & ");FALSE;IF(AND(IF(ISERR(RIGHT(" & s_adr_1 & ")*1);NOT(ISERR(FIND(" & s_adr_2 & ";" & s_adr_1 & ")));TRUE));FALSE;IF(LEFT(" & s_adr_1 & ")=""#"";FALSE;ISERR(FIND(" & s_adr_2 & ";" & s_adr_1 & "))))))))"
```

Where s_adr_1 and s_adr_2 are a references to cells so it can look like this as a sample (in B1 there will be my test text, like e.g. "5-15", "15", "5...15"):

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=IF(ISERR(FIND(" & Chr(34) & "-" & Chr(34) & ";" & "B1" & ";2))=FALSE;TRUE;IF(ISERR(FIND(" & Chr(34) & "…" & Chr(34) & ";" & "B1" & ";2))=FALSE;TRUE;IF(ISERR(FIND(" & Chr(34) & ".." & Chr(34) & ";" & "B1" & "))=FALSE;TRUE;IF(ISBLANK(" & "B1" & ");FALSE;IF(AND(IF(ISERR(RIGHT(" & "B1" & ")*1);NOT(ISERR(FIND(" & "C1" & ";" & "B1" & ")));TRUE));FALSE;IF(LEFT(" & "B1" & ")=""#"";FALSE;ISERR(FIND(" & "C1" & ";" & "B1" & "))))))))"
```

Expected outcome in A1 would be:

```
=IF(ISERR(FIND("-";B1;2))=FALSE;TRUE;IF(ISERR(FIND("…";B1;2))=FALSE;TRUE;IF(ISERR(FIND("..";B1))=FALSE;TRUE;IF(ISBLANK(B1);FALSE;IF(AND(IF(ISERR(RIGHT(B1)*1);NOT(ISERR(FIND(C$1;B1)));TRUE));FALSE;IF(LEFT(B1)="#";FALSE;ISERR(FIND(C$1;B1))))))))
```

It should return TRUE or FALSE.

When I try to run the code I got Error 1004 :(

What is wrong here? Why it works when I paste it in Excel manually?

Comment: You need to replace your ";" by "," .

Comment: Why the Reopen vote? What solution to this is not adequately covered multiple times by the three duplicate examples I provided?

Comment: It didn't work when I changed ";" to ",". This formula has to be inserted and work in Excel sheet, so I don't need the outcome but a formula in a cell

Comment: @Jeeped - when I have voted it was only one - "Different Languages ..." and this was not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using English Excel version, simply use double quotes in the VBA version. Or pretty much do the following:

- write the formula in Excel and select the cell, where it is
- run this code and mimic the formula, that you get:

-

```
Public Sub PrintMeUsefulFormula()

    Dim strFormula  As String
    Dim strParenth  As String

    strParenth = """"

    strFormula = Selection.Formula
    strFormula = Replace(strFormula, """", """""")

    strFormula = strParenth & strFormula & strParenth
    Debug.Print strFormula

End Sub
```

Comment: VBA'S .Formula will not accept semi-colons as a list separator. Either use commas or switch to .FormulaLocal.

Comment: It didn't work :( and also the whole code will be used in Polish, Norwegian and Finnish version of Excel :(

Comment: @MariuszWach - what have you tried? What have you received? What did not work?

Comment: @Vityata I tried your code, I also tried to manually change "-" to ""-"" etc

Comment: @MariuszWach - before trying the code, you should have done 2 things - First writing the formula in Excel correctly and Second - selecting the cell. Have you done these? What have you received in the immediate window?

Comment: @Vityata It worked now, amazing. I pasted wrong formula. Thanks a lot! I received correct formula for VBA 
        =IF(ISERR(FIND("-";K3;2))=FALSE;TRUE;IF(ISERR(FIND("…";K3;2))=FALSE;TRUE;IF(ISERR(FIND("..";K3))=FALSE;TRUE;IF(ISBLANK(K3);FALSE;IF(AND(IF(ISERR(RIGHT(K3)*1);NOT(ISERR(FIND(K$6;K3)));TRUE));FALSE;IF(LEFT(K3)="#";FALSE;ISERR(FIND(K$6;K3))))))))

Comment: @MariuszWach - congrats!